# How to find string in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object:

```
var listRegions = { 
    "center": [ '7' ],
    "south": [ '12' ],
    "north": [ '11' ],
    "west": [ '4' ]
};
```

Now, how can I look for value? Normally I looking for indexes, like 'center', 'north', etc. but now I need to find value, like '7', '12', etc.
How can I do this?

Comment: what is the goal, to check the occurrence of value or to return all elements which have specified values?

Answer (score 1):

To find 7

```
var results = Object.keys(listRegions).filter(function(val){ return listRegions[val].indexOf(7) != -1 });
```

This will give you items in `listRegions`  which has value 7